# Restore database db2 get error SQLSTATE=57019

Tags: db2

After install IBM data server, i have one administrator user. I log this user into win 10.

```
 db2 => create database sss   (successful)
 db2 => connect to sss
 db2 => restore database sss from d:\
```

Drive D: has backup file. I also used `create database sss` to make database before. When i backup, i let backup file in drive D:. But i get error :

SQL2523W  Warning!  Restoring to an existing database that is different from
the database on the backup image, but have matching names. The target database
will be overwritten by the backup version.  The Roll-forward recovery logs
associated with the target database will be deleted.
Do you want to continue ? (y/n) y

SQL1051N  The path "E:" does not exist or is not valid.  SQLSTATE=57019

What is Drive E:. I never used that drive E:

My test.clp :

```
UPDATE COMMAND OPTIONS USING S ON Z ON SSS_NODE0000.out V ON;
SET CLIENT ATTACH_MEMBER  0;
SET CLIENT CONNECT_MEMBER 0;
RESTORE DATABASE SSS
-- USER  <username>
-- USING '<password>'
FROM 'd:\'
TAKEN AT 20210603080520
-- ON 'E:'
-- DBPATH ON '<target-directory>'
INTO SSS
-- NEWLOGPATH 'E:\DB2\NODE0000\SQL00002\LOGSTREAM0000\'
-- WITH <num-buff> BUFFERS
-- BUFFER <buffer-size>
-- REPLACE HISTORY FILE
-- REPLACE EXISTING
REDIRECT
-- PARALLELISM <n>
WITHOUT ROLLING FORWARD
```

-- WITHOUT PROMPTING
;
-- ** storage group definition
-- **   Default storage group ID                 = 0
-- **   Number of storage groups                 = 1
-- ** Storage group name                         = IBMSTOGROUP
-- **   Storage group ID                         = 0
-- **   Data tag                                 = None
-- -- SET STOGROUP PATHS FOR IBMSTOGROUP
-- ON 'E:'
-- ;
-- ** table space definition
-- ** Tablespace name                            = SYSCATSPACE
-- **   Tablespace ID                            = 0
-- **   Tablespace Type                          = Database managed
space
-- **   Tablespace Content Type                  = All permanent
data. Regular table space.
-- **   Tablespace Page size (bytes)             = 4096
-- **   Tablespace Extent size (pages)           = 4
-- **   Using automatic storage                  = Yes
-- **   Storage group ID                         = 0
-- **   Source storage group ID                  = -1
-- **   Data tag                                 = None
-- **   Auto-resize enabled                      = Yes
-- **   Total number of pages                    = 32768
-- **   Number of usable pages                   = 32764
-- **   High water mark (pages)                  = 31016
-- ** Tablespace name                            = TEMPSPACE1
-- **   Tablespace ID                            = 1
-- **   Tablespace Type                          = System managed
space
-- **   Tablespace Content Type                  = System Temporary
data
-- **   Tablespace Page size (bytes)             = 4096
-- **   Tablespace Extent size (pages)           = 32
-- **   Using automatic storage                  = Yes
-- **   Total number of pages                    = 1
-- ** Tablespace name                            = USERSPACE1
-- **   Tablespace ID                            = 2
-- **   Tablespace Type                          = Database managed
space
-- **   Tablespace Content Type                  = All permanent
data. Large table space.
-- **   Tablespace Page size (bytes)             = 4096
-- **   Tablespace Extent size (pages)           = 32
-- **   Using automatic storage                  = Yes
-- **   Storage group ID                         = 0
-- **   Source storage group ID                  = -1
-- **   Data tag                                 = -1
-- **   Auto-resize enabled                      = Yes
-- **   Total number of pages                    = 8192
-- **   Number of usable pages                   = 8160
-- **   High water mark (pages)                  = 544

```
-- ** Tablespace name                            = SYSTOOLSPACE
-- **   Tablespace ID                            = 3
-- **   Tablespace Type                          = Database managed 
space                      
 -- **   Tablespace Content Type                  = All permanent 
data. Large table space.      
-- **   Tablespace Page size (bytes)             = 4096
-- **   Tablespace Extent size (pages)           = 4
-- **   Using automatic storage                  = Yes     
-- **   Storage group ID                         = 0
-- **   Source storage group ID                  = -1
-- **   Data tag                                 = -1
-- **   Auto-resize enabled                      = Yes     
-- **   Total number of pages                    = 8192
-- **   Number of usable pages                   = 8188
-- **   High water mark (pages)                  = 152
-- ** start redirected restore
RESTORE DATABASE SSS CONTINUE;
-- ** end of file
```

Comment: Mistakes.  Don't create the database if you wish to restore it. Do not connect to a database you want to restore. If you want to overwrite an existing database you need to explicitly tell restore to do that. If the backup image is from either a different hostname or a different Db2 instance it may have different paths (e.g. E:\) and if so, you will need a redirected restore.   These are not programming matters. They are simple administration, so you should read the docs before asking.

Comment: I forget hostname, the DB2 instance is default. How can i do next. I just install new win 10

Comment: Refer to the [Performing a redirected restore using an automatically generated script](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=operation-performing-redirected-restore-using-automatically-generated-script) article.

Comment: db2 => restore db sss from d:\  taken at 20210603080520  redirect generate script test.clp. I get error :  SQL9304N  Unable to open file "test.clp" for writing.  SQLSTATE=00000. Although i create database sss

Comment: @nam It's a file access problem. Choose some full path where you are allowed to write to.

Comment: db2 =>  -tvf d:\test.clp
I get error : DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0007N  The statement was not processed because a character that is not
supported in SQL statements was included in the SQL statement.  Invalid
character: "\".  Text preceding the invalid character: "-tvf d:".
SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Run the following from Start -> Run -> db2cwadmin.bat **as is**: `db2 restore db sss from d:\ taken at 20210603080520 redirect generate script d:\test.clp`

Comment: I also run db2cwadmin.bat. I create test.clp successful. db2 =>  -tvf d:\test.clp
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0007N  The statement was not processed because a character that is not
supported in SQL statements was included in the SQL statement.  Invalid
character: "\".  Text preceding the invalid character: "-tvf d:".
SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: You must run the script from a command window (not from an interactive db2 clp prompt) like this: `d:\> db2 -tvf d:\test.clp`.

Answer (score 0):

D:>db2 -tvf d:\test.clp
UPDATE COMMAND OPTIONS USING S ON Z ON SSS_NODE0000.out V ON
DB20000I  The UPDATE COMMAND OPTIONS command completed successfully.

SET CLIENT ATTACH_MEMBER  0
DB20000I  The SET CLIENT command completed successfully.

SET CLIENT CONNECT_MEMBER 0
DB20000I  The SET CLIENT command completed successfully.

RESTORE DATABASE SSS FROM 'd:' TAKEN AT 20210603080520 INTO SSS REDIRECT WITHOUT ROLLING FORWARD
SQL2523W  Warning!  Restoring to an existing database that is different from
the database on the backup image, but have matching names. The target database
will be overwritten by the backup version.  The Roll-forward recovery logs
associated with the target database will be deleted.
Do you want to continue ? (y/n) y

SQL1277W  A redirected restore operation is being performed. During a table
space restore, only table spaces being restored can have their paths
reconfigured. During a database restore, storage group storage paths and DMS
table space containers can be reconfigured.
DB20000I  The RESTORE DATABASE command completed successfully.

RESTORE DATABASE SSS CONTINUE

SQL1051N  The path "E:" does not exist or is not valid.  SQLSTATE=57019

Comment: Please, don't answer your own question with error you get. Edit your question with contents of `d:\test.clp` you use to run this command. Seems, that you haven't edited it accordingly.

Comment: Because the error report is too long, so i can't post at comment position. So i post at answer position. I don't know anything to edit d:/test.clp

Comment: I asked you to edit your initial question with content of this file, not to post an "error report" as a comment. Either edit the test.clp on your own to exclude all references to not available drive and run this script again or show full content of this file, if you don't understand how to edit it properly.